# How can I call a factory function's getter method within a Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a factory function, and if that's not standard lingo, I'm referring to a function which returns an object. This factory function is called `Person`. I'll say now - I don't want to hear 'Use a constructor'. Factory functions are better.

I also have an array of objects, `allPeople` made using this factory function.

In case it's not clear from my use of 'factory function', the objects are actually objects containing the getter method, `getPerson` in this case, among other functions, (the produced objects being differentiated by closure scope). To get the actual data, one must call `getPerson()` on a `Person` object (an object produced by the `Person` function).

I thought I should explain that just so we're on the same basis.

I am trying to use Handlebars to insert an element for each `Person` object in `allPeople`. For each `Person`, a `<p>` element will display the `name` value and another `<p>` element will display the `age` value.

Below I include the js file and the html file.

**script.js**

```
//Factory Function
const Person = (givenName, givenAge) => {
    theName = givenName;
    age = givenAge;
    const getPerson = () => {
        const obj = { theName, age };
        return { theName, age };
    }
    return {getPerson};
}
//DOM Element Access
const templateElement = document.getElementById('templateHB');
const templateDestination = document.getElementById('destination');
//Context
allPeople = [
    Person('Jim', 32),
    Person('Lily', 46)
];
const context = {
    people: allPeople
};
//Templating
const template = Handlebars.compile(templateElement.innerHTML);
const compiledHTML = template(context);
templateDestination.innerHTML = compiledHTML;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en">
<head>
    <meta charset"UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>For SO use</title>
    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./handlebars.js"></script>
    <script id="templateHB" type="text/x-handlebars-template" defer>
        {{#each people}}
        <p>{{this.getPerson().theName}}</p>
        <p>{{this.getPerson().age}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="destination">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open index.html in a browser (I've tried Google Chrome and Firefox), the following error happens:

> ..... `<p>{{this.getPerson().theName}`^
> Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

How can I properly implement this design?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your post that you are not looking for recommendations against using this "factory function". However, I feel that my post would be incomplete if I did not state that I do not see the value in this code and I think it makes things needlessly complicated.

But let's proceed with the "factory function".

There is a problem with it. The fact that you have not put `var` or `const` or `let` before each of the assignments `theName = givenName` and `age = givenAge` means that `theName` and `age` are globally scoped and therefore any call to `getPerson()` is going to return the `theName` and `age` of the parameters supplied to the last call of `Person()`.

Once that is fixed, I would recommend leaving your template blissfully unaware of the "factory function". You could do this by mapping your `allPeople` array into plain-ol' regular objects that everyone understands:

```
const allPeople = [
  Person('Jim', 32),
  Person('Lily', 46)
].map(person => person.getPerson());
```

Your (simplified) template would become:

```
{{#each people}}
  <p>{{theName}}</p>
  <p>{{age}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/yf7euj9g/) is a fiddle of a working example.

If, for some reason, you really want your template to deal with the `getPerson` method, then I think you will need a custom Handlebars helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getPersonProperty', function (person, property) {
  return person.getPerson()[property];
});
```

Using this helper in your template would look like:

```
{{#each people}}
  <p>{{getPersonProperty this 'theName'}}</p>
  <p>{{getPersonProperty this 'age'}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/yf7euj9g/) is a fiddle with an example of this.

Comment: @Keith Rubin I would like to know if this was helpful to you.